# Position of Redirects and RewriteRules in .htaccess for WordPress site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect URLs from an old Drupal site to a new WordPress site with a different domain name. The Drupal site contains thousands of genetic tests, but the client will only continue to offer a hundred tests on the WordPress site.

In the `.htaccess` file on the WordPress site I created the redirects and tested them all. They're working fine. Here's an example:

```
Redirect 301 /test/detail/kptn-defect-syndrome-targeted-testing https://www.example.org/genetic_test/kptn-disorder-kptn-targeted-testing/ 
Redirect 301 /test/detail/herc2-defect-syndrome-targeted-testing https://www.example.org/genetic_test/herc2-disorder-herc2-targeted-testing/ 
Redirect 301 /test/detail/hemophilia-b-f9-targeted-testing https://www.example.org/genetic_test/hemophilia-b-f9-targeted-testing/
```

I also created a wildcard redirect so that all other tests that are no longer being offered will resolve to their new lab page:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /test/(.*) https://www.example.org/about-our-lab/
```

This too is working fine.

My question is where in the `.htaccess` file do I place the rewriterule pointing the old domain to the new domain? And does it all come before the WordPress generated directives?
Here's my rewriterule:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)old\.example$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^https://www.newexample.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I want to get this right so when I shut down the old Drupal site and point the domain to the server with the WordPress site everything works without issues. Currently I have all redirects above the WordPress directives. Would the rewriterule go above also, and would it go above the redirects?

UPDATE:

This is not working. I created the .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?newexample\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=52]

RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?test/detail/factor-v-leiden-f5-targeted-testing$ https://www.newexample.org/genetic_test/factor-v-leiden-f5-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?test/detail/dystonia-6-torsion-thap1-targeted-testing$ https://www.newexample.org/genetic_test/torsion-dystonia-6-thap1-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?test/detail/deafness-and-myopia-slitrk6-targeted-testing$ https://www.newexample.org/genetic_test/deafness-and-myopia-slitrk6-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L]
(... and so on ...)

# Redirect all other tests to generic page
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?test/ https://www.newexample.org/about-our-lab/ [R=301,L]

# Redirect everything else to new domain (same URL)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newexample.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Worpress directives below.
```

But it is not working when I test newexample.org/test/detail/factor-v-leiden-f5-targeted-testing it does not redirect me to the new test page corresponding to the end of the applicable RewriteRule. Instead WordPress responds "Post not found."

Why is this not working?

UPDATE:

It does work as shown above. To test it I had to change the RewriteCond to another domain and comment out the generic RewriteRule. Thanks for pointing that our Mr White.

All is well. And many many thanks to Mr White.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...when I shut down the old Drupal site and point the domain to the server with the Wordpress site everything works without issues.

If the old and new domains are going to be pointing to the same host then you need to convert all the redirects you have just implemented that use mod_alias `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives to use mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` instead.

This is because mod_rewrite is processed first, despite the apparent order of the directives in the `.htaccess` file, so your *generic* redirect (that uses mod_rewrite) to redirect all remaining URLs would be processed first - resulting in 2 redirects for all your `/test/` URLs. Ok, it will still "work", but it's not ideal.

Generally, you should not mix redirects from both mod_alias and mod_rewrite in the same context as you can get unexpected redirects due to the order of processing.

Another potential issue with the redirects you have implemented is that you aren't checking the hostname, so you can't have URLs that start `/test/` on the new domain. You don't need to check the hostname for every rule, as they can be "grouped" together.

> Would the rewriterule go above also, and would it go above the redirects?

All these redirects (that use mod_rewrite) must go *before* the WordPress code block, otherwise they will simply never be processed. mod_alias redirects could potentially be placed anywhere.

> ```
> #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)oldexample\.org$ [NC]
> #RewriteRule ^https://www.newexample.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

You are missing a *space* between the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st arg) and the *substitution* string (2nd arg), so this will fail to redirect as written.

You are also missing the `?` after the parenthesised subpattern in the *CondPattern*, assuming the `www` subdomain is intended to be optional.

Bringing the above points together, the redirects could be written like this:

```
# If the "new domain" is already requested then skip the next 102 rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?newexample\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=102]

RewriteRule ^test/detail/kptn-defect-syndrome-targeted-testing$ https://www.example.org/genetic_test/kptn-disorder-kptn-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^test/detail/herc2-defect-syndrome-targeted-testing$ https://www.example.org/genetic_test/herc2-disorder-herc2-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^test/detail/hemophilia-b-f9-targeted-testing$ https://www.example.org/genetic_test/hemophilia-b-f9-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L]
# etc....

# Redirect all other tests to generic page
RewriteRule ^test/ https://www.example.org/about-our-lab/ [R=301,L]

# Redirect everything else to new domain (same URL)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newexample.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# WordPress directives follow...
```

You just need to be careful to count the number of rules to skip. I've used 102 above as you said they would "continue to offer a hundred tests" (so, 100 redirects), plus the 2 generic redirects that follow.

You don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, since that already occurs *later* in the file (in the WordPress code block). It is the last instance of this directive that does anything anyway, so if you repeat `RewriteEngine` it is arguably misleading.

**Alternatively**, you could have a second `.htaccess` file in a `/redirect-old-urls` subdirectory and internally rewrite all requests for the old domain to this subdirectory first. This has an advantage of keeping all the "old" redirects out of the main `.htaccess` file, with only a minimal change to the main `.htaccess` file.

For example:

In the main `.htaccess` file in the root:

```
# /.htaccess

# Requests for the old domain are internally rewritten to a subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldexample\.org [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) redirect-old-urls/$1 [L]

# WordPress directives follow...
```

Then, in the `/redirect-old-urls/.htaccess` file:

```
# /redirect-old-urls/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^test/detail/kptn-defect-syndrome-targeted-testing$ https://www.example.org/genetic_test/kptn-disorder-kptn-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^test/detail/herc2-defect-syndrome-targeted-testing$ https://www.example.org/genetic_test/herc2-disorder-herc2-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^test/detail/hemophilia-b-f9-targeted-testing$ https://www.example.org/genetic_test/hemophilia-b-f9-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L]
# etc....

# Redirect all other tests to generic page
RewriteRule ^test/ https://www.example.org/about-our-lab/ [R=301,L]

# Redirect everything else to new domain (same URL)
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newexample.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path relative to the directory-prefix, so it does not include `redirect-old-urls/`. It is for this reason that I also changed the last "catch-all" rule to use a backreference and not the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, that includes the full URL-path (including the arbitrary `redirect-old-urls/` URL-path prefix).

Any direct requests to the subdirectory (if any) would be redirected back to root by the last rule.

---

**Alternatively**, If you have access to the main server config then this could be implemented more efficiently with a `RewriteMap` that contains the mapping of old "test" URLs to new.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed explanation. I have a few questions:

Comment: I noticed that your first RewriteRule `RewriteRule ^test/detail/kptn-defect-syndrome-targeted-testing$ https://www.example.org/genetic_test/kptn-disorder-kptn-targeted-testing/ [R=301,L]` contained $ at the end of the path, but not subsequent ones. Was this a simple oversight?
I also notice that you do not have the initial / in the path. Is it wrong to include it?
Finally, I need two versions of each RewriteRule with the following paths:
^test/detail/... $ and ^index.php/test/detail/... $
to ensure I have non-friendly URLs covered too. Is there a simpler way to handle this?

Comment: @banacan Sorry, yes, the other `RewriteRule` directives in that block should really have `$` at the end of the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. I've updated my answer. (Although it would work without.) There's obviously no `$` after `^test/` in the generic rule, or on the condition that checks the hostname, ie. `^(www\.)?oldexample\.org` (to allow for fully qualified domains that end in a dot).

Comment: @banacan "I also notice that you do not have the initial / in the path." - Yes, that is correct. In `.htaccess`, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against does not start with a slash. If you include the slash prefix then the rule will not match and it won't do anything. (This is different to when mod_rewrite is used in a server or virtualhost context - in this case the URL-path that is matched is root-relative, including the slash prefix!)

Comment: @banacan "I need two versions of each RewriteRule" - You only need one rule to handle both URLs. The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is a regular expression (regex), so you can just make the `index.php/` part optional. eg. `RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?test/detail/....$`

Comment: Your response has been so helpful. I'm copying everything you wrote so I have it for further reference. I'm especially pleased about the last point - only needing one rule with part optional. 
And I appreciate the samples you included which clearly show the relative position of the directives in the htaccess file. I know from past experience how fussy these things are, and something in the wrong position won't do anything.
Thanks again for all of your time and effort.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. In the first example you gave the first RewriteCond showed the new domain `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?newexample\.org [NC]` shouldn't it be the old domain? `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldexample\.org [NC]`
I want to be sure I have this right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257192/discussion-between-banacan-and-mrwhite).

Comment: @banacan No, it's correct to have the "new domain" there. That rule states that if a request comes in for the "new domain" then the next 102 rules are skipped (`S` flag). So, the redirects are only processed for requests that are _not_ the "new domain", ie. the old domain. (I assuming you don't have any more domains, other than "old" and "new"?)